# Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Tags: php, sql

```
$inicial = $_POST['codigoInicial'];

$final = $_POST['codigoFinal'];


$c2=0;

$sql2 = "select D.nombre_dire, 
I.CodInformeAud,
R.Conclusion_reco,
R.Recomendacion_reco,
S.FechaSegRecCont,
I.NombreInfContr,
S.nombre_evidencia,
S.DescripEvidencia from RecomendacionesCont R
join DireccionArea D ON R.DireccionArea_reco=D.idDireccionArea
join Funcionario F ON R.Funcionario_reco=F.idFuncionario
join InformeContraloria I ON R.CodInformeAud_reco=I.IdInfCont
join SeguimientoRecCont S ON R.IdRecomendacionCont=S.IdRecomendacionCont
join Cargo C ON F.id_cargo_func=C.id_cargo
where I.CodInformeAud>=".$inicial." and I.CodInformeAud<=".$final."
order by D.nombre_dire,I.CodInformeAud,S.FechaSegRecCont";

$content2 .='<br><br><table>
<thead class="mdb-color darken-3">
        <tr class="text-white">
            <td>Nombre Dirección</td>
            <td>Codigo de Informe</td>
            <td>Nombre de Informe</td>
            <td>Conclusión</td>
            <td>Recomendación</td>
            <td>Fecha Seguimiento</td>
            <td>Nombre de Evidencia</td>
            <td>Descripción Evidencia</td>

        </tr>
</thead>';

$result=sqlsrv_query($con,$sql2);

while($mostrar=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$c2=$c2+1;
$content2 .= '
<tr>
<td>'.$mostrar["nombre_dire"].'</td>
<td>'.$mostrar["CodInformeAud"].'</td>
<td>'.$mostrar["NombreInfContr"].'</td>
<td>'.substr($mostrar['Conclusion_reco'],0,120).'</td>
<td>'.substr($mostrar['Recomendacion_reco'],0,120).'</td>
<td>'.$mostrar["FechaSegRecCont"]->format('Y-m-d').'</td>
<td>'.$mostrar['nombre_evidencia'].'</td>
<td>'.$mostrar['DescripEvidencia'].'</td>
</tr>';
}
$content2 .= '<tr> 
                <td>Total Reportes:</td><td>'.$c2.'</td>
            </tr>';
$content2 .='</table>';
```

Comment: Tengo problemas con los parametros, porque si le pongo los datos directamente sin usar variables,  me muestra resultados

Comment: Imprime la consulta y revísala: `echo $sql2;` No se sabe lo que estás recibiendo en el POST, o si esos datos están llegando vacíos. Además tu código es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Tenlo en cuenta para cuando hagas funcionar la consulta, pues es un peligro grave.

Comment: La consulta esta bien porque la ejecuto desde el sql server y funciona bien, el problema creo que es en la concatenación, y lo de la consulta va a ir en un procedimiento almacenado

Answer (score 0):

Eso suele deberse a un error en la consulta MySQL y cuando realizas el fetch_assoc() se lo estás haciendo a un valor **boolean**.

Para evitar este tipo de roturas en los scripts, es una buena práctica comprobar el error de la query antes de realizar la extracción de los datos.

```php
$result = sqlsrv_query( $con, $sql2 );

if( $error = sqlsrv_errors() != null ) {
    // Realizar las tareas necesarias si la consulta falla.

    error_log( $error );
    die();
}

while($mostrar=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    // ......
```

Comment: por favor se tan amable de leer [answer], si el error esta en la consulta entonces por favor indica de manera clara donde esta el error y como tu aporte lo corrige, considera que esto lo van a consultar muchos usuarios y no a todos les quedará claro de que hablas